# ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt not generated

Tags: certificate, jmeter, recorder

I am new to JMeter. I believe I have installed it successfully and I am running through the script recorder setup (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf). When I start the JMeter proxy server which is used to intercept the browser requests a file called ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt should be generated in jmeter/bin folder. It isn't. So, I cannot move on to Install the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording, or for that matter configure my browser. Is there any known reason why the JMeter certificate would fail to be generated?

Comment: https://youtu.be/bTEtE9oyZzA?t=256 A bit hacky but worked for me. When using the JMeter HTTPS recorder test meter automatically generates the ca cert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using Java 6 , in this case no ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA is generated.

To know if you are using Java 7:
- If HTTPS Domains is read only you are in JDK6
- If HTTPS Domains is writable you are using JDK7

Ensure you follow this:

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

Comment: Thanks! I had the JDK, just the wrong path in the jmeter.sh file. I'd up vote your answer, but I am such a newbie that I can't.

Comment: You need to have at least 15 points, which seems you have no. At least you should accept answer so that it's helpful to others.

Answer (score 15):

I solved it by removing `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`, `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr` and **`proxyserver.jks`** from the bin directory of JMeter.

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-issues/201401.mbox/%3Cbug-56057-58895@https.issues.apache.org/bugzilla/%3E

Comment: Only this worked for me, I had already deleted the certificates, I had also to delete `proxyserver.jks`.

Answer (score 2):

Need to remove `proxyserver.jks` to create new certificate if you have removed `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`, `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr` from bin . I did same too and got the certificate.

Comment: Thank you, yes if you delete the certificate also be sure to delete proxyserver.jks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue - the root certificate was not found under the jmeter/bin directory. It was created in this path

C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume3\Users{UserName}\Downloads\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin

I had to import it to firefox

Windows 7 Professional - 64 bit
Java 7 - 64 bit 
Jmeter Version 2.12

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. It appeared that the keytool.exe file that was being called by JMeter to generate the certificate, was located in a directory that had no write access. Initially the certificate is generated relatively to the location of keytool.exe (which is in java/bin), and then it is moved into the jmeter/bin directory.

We were able to fix it by copying the java installation directory into de jmeter directory and set write access. Then start JMeter with java pointing to the copied version.

Don't forget to remove proxyserver.jks before you try again

Comment: On Windows 7, had the same issue here and got it fix by just coping the key tool.exe into the Jmeter bin directory

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue please follow below steps,

1.Reinstall java, update the environment variables JAVA_HOME

2.Check the java version and make sure you don't get anything extra other than
C:>java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
in case if you find anything addition , remove them from environment variables.

5.Run Jmeter , you should be getting root certification

Answer (score 0):

don't go complex solution lets try it easily

1. check your jdk version java -version> if version is less then jdk6 then update you jdk
   2.download the missing file (gist.github.com/9ef114c53b83e553b635.git)
   3 and add it however you know

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

I extracted JMeter in *C: drive (Windows 10 program files folder)*.

**Running JMeter.bat as Administrator** solved that issue for me.

Otherwise extracting in other drives also help.