# Apache jMeter not generating ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt for https recording

Tags: certificate, jmeter

I am having a particular problem with jMeter 2.10 that is not solved by any of the responses I have found either here or elsewhere. When I follow the procedure for recording https, at the point where I start the 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder', I get the pop-up informing me:

```
 Root CA Certificate: ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA created in JMeter bin directory
   (etc., etc.…)
```

I check the bin directory. No certificate has been created.

I have tailed the log file while performing these steps and at the point when I start
the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, an entry is written to the log (today's example):

```
 2014/01/22 13:58:57 WARN - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Problem reading
  key storeNotAfter: Tue Jan 07 09:12:09 MST 2014
```

Except for the WARN in the log, JMeter behaves as if it has created the .crt file but it
does not. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need further information, I would
be happy to provide it.

My Configuration is as follows:

```
Windows 7.
jMeter 2.10.
C:\>java -version
  java version "1.7.0_09"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
Java executed from the command line calls:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin\java.exe
JMETER_HOME points to the JMeter 2.10 installation base.
JAVA_HOME points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09
keytool.exe is on the path and resides in:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin
The folder: %JMETER_HOME%\bin is writable and JMeter can write to it
  (evidenced by log).
```

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053346/apachejmetertemporaryrootca-crt-not-generated/28711262#28711262. Only it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout JMeter 2.11, it contains many improvements in this field and will indicate to you the issue.

- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Comment: The 2.11 install does create a .crt file.

To test repeatability, I removed .crt and .usr files (.usr was created with .crt). Tried again. NO new .crt, NO log WARN.

Compared bin with original and found another new file proxyserver.jks. Removed this also, and tried again. Got a new .crt, .usr, and .jks.

Dump of .jks suggests it caches .crt info somehow. JMeter must think the .crt is still there without checking for it if .jks exists.

Only thing I cannot check is if I will get a new .crt when the fresh one expires without deleting the three files.

At least I can make it work. THANK YOU!

Comment: you should accept answer then. Also I suggest you open a bugzilla with your scenario.

Comment: FYI, I opened a Bugzilla as suggested. The report can be found at:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56057

Comment: 2.11 behaves the same way. The comment and discussion at the bugzilla link are more useful.