# Apache jMeter is not generating ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt certificate for http request recording

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm following step by step this tutorial to create the certificate ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt.

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

However after I hit run nothing related to certificate is showing up, as if I was just running a simple test without recording. It's not even displaying error messages. I have read these threads but they are not helpful for my case:

Does any
 - [Apache jMeter not generating ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt for https recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294354/apache-jmeter-not-generating-apachejmetertemporaryrootca-crt-for-https-recording)
 - [ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053346/apachejmetertemporaryrootca-crt-not-generated)

I am using Java 1.7.0,67, Jmeter 2.13 (both are newest versions). I have also followed this page to set up my environment variables

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210

Does anyone has an idea about what is missing here?
Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem where I'd deleted the certificate and struggled to get it to regenerate.

In the bin folder there is a keystore file called proxyserver.jks, when I deleted that the certificate regenerated on the next start of the test script recorder

Comment: This solved my issue. Your answer is a proof that one can make meaningful contribution even to 5 years old question!

Answer (score 1):

In the absolute majority of cases *jmeter.log* file contains all the answers or at least can help to figure out the cause of the problem.

If below checklist doesn't help - update your question with relevant bit of the JMeter log file.

1. Use [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html), not JRE
2. Make sure that you have the following environment variables set:

   - [JAVA_HOME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html) - pointing to JDK installation root
   - [PATH](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) - contains /bin folder of JAVA_HOME
3. If you using web browser for recording make sure that

   - "HTTP Proxy" is set to correct JMeter host and port
   - "Use proxy for all protocols" box is checked
   - "No proxy for" input doesn't filter out JMeter host (you can clean it)

   Refer below image for example proxy settings for Firefox browser:

[image: Firefox Proxy Settings]

4. The easiest way to set up JMeter for recording is using Recording Template (File -> Templates -> Recording), this way you can get JMeter configured for recording in a single click

If above checklist didn't resolve your problem check out [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) guide for troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, and click the Start button at the bottom.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

> This will start the JMeter proxy server which is used to intercept the browser requests.
>   A file called ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt will be generated in jmeter/bin folder.

Possibly you run test instead of starting proxy server.