# Not able to do Jmeter UI recording due to CORS error

Tags: jmeter-4.0

We are facing CORS issue in Jmeter UI recording:

```
CORS request did not succeed
```

We have website uat.torchmarkets.com which internally calls tradeuat.torchmarkets.com in which has security check for Cross Domain Request. Sharing. We want to do UI recoding for uat.torchmarkets.com

Below is jmeter UI recorder setting

[image: ￼[JmeterUIRecordingSetting]

Below is proxy settings in browser. The subdomain loadtesting.torchmarkets.com is whitelisted.

[image: ￼[BrowserProxySetting]

Below is there CORS error

[image: [CORSError]
￼

Any help to solve this issue will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4):

In my case the CORS error vanished after importing JMeter's certificate.

In JMeter's bin folder, you will find a .crt file. This one needs to be imported into the browser. I have tested it only with Firefox.

1. In Firefox, go to  `Privacy & Security` settings section where you
   find `View Certificates...`
2. Select the `Authorities` tab
3. Click on `Import...` and browse for JMeter's certificate
4. Check `This certificate can identify web sites.` and confirm

From that point on you should see no further CORS errors, until the certificate expires, which is by default 7 days.

Optionally, in the bin folder of JMeter find the file `jmeter.properties` and change the validity period of the certificate if you need it for longer than the default 7 days by changing the value `proxy.cert.validity` and [let the certificate regenerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053346/apachejmetertemporaryrootca-crt-not-generated).